# NSIS installer opens in background.

Tags: nsis, nsis-mui

I have tried using bringtofront  but I dont beleive that is what I actually want. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Could you give more informations ? Are you starting a NSIS installer from another program ? If so what language ?

Comment: the exe file is downloaded from a webpage and opens for the user to install the application. if there are other windows open it will open behind them

Comment: but who is starting the setup ? The user from the web browser ? Another application that you made ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plugins could cause focus issues, try a script without any code in `.onInit` and `.onGuiInit`. If it still happens you can file a bug report with a simple example script and the required steps to reproduce (Browser and operating system version etc)

Comment: i have found that it is because i am calling inetc::get during .onInit. Are you aware of any fix for this?

Comment: Yeah that was one of the first things I did. - No Luck.

Comment: @user1228637 Try moving the plugin call to .onGuiInit or the show callback for your first page. Or try the (experimental?) InetBgDL plugin...

Comment: Thank you Anders looks like  InetBgDL did it!